# Store 2 values in a node separated by horizontal line in the middle

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have the following Binary tree:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
           every node/.style={draw,circle}]
        \node {10}
            child{node{5}}
            child{node{20}}
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Binary Tree]

Is there a way to split each node in two by adding a horizontal line at the center of each node, then adding a value above and below the line?

I want to create an augmented binary tree where each node will store additional value outside of the key.

EDIT:

The closest behavior I can get is by making the numbers into fractions instead. But it doesn't look that nice. I don't want someone to think it is a fraction instead of 2 different numbers.

EDIT AGAIN:

Thank you both for the answer. It seems to work great. The only issue i'm currently facing is that there seems to be a horizontal line added under labels as well. Is there a way to get rid of the lines only for the labels?:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={circle split,draw}]
        \node [label=330:$0$]{10\nodepart{lower}1}
            child{node[label=330:$1$]{5\nodepart{lower}2}}
            child{node[label=330:$2$]{20\nodepart{lower}3}}
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Binary Tree]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For node use `circle split` shape from `shapes.multipart` TikZ library:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={circle split,draw}
                        ]
        \node {10\nodepart{lower}1}
            child{ node { 5\nodepart{lower}2}}
            child{ node {20\nodepart{lower}3}}
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:** In case, that you like to add labels to nodes in tree, than you can't use style for every node, since it is applied to label too. Workaround is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
X/.style={circle split,draw}
                        ]
        \node[X,label=330:$0$] {10\nodepart{lower}1}
            child{ node[X] { 5\nodepart{lower}2}}
            child{ node[X] {20\nodepart{lower}3}}
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it looks really nice! But when I add a label to a node, it seems to draw the horizontal line under the label as well. Is it possible to get rid of it only for the label?

Example of node with label: child{node[label=330:$0$]{1\nodepart{lower}1}}

Comment: What you discover, is consequence of use `every node/.style` which is also applied to labels (which is special kind of node). Se addendum to my answer.